# Is it possible to create duplicate LabeledPoints and multi valued LabeledPoints in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using pyspark's linear regression algorithm. while preparing data (collection of LabeledPoints)..can i give duplicate LabeledPoint and can i give multiple label values for a specific combination of independent variables ?

For example :
Case 1:
LabeledPoint(1, [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]),
LabeledPoint(1, [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]),

Case 2:
LabeledPoint(2, [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]),
LabeledPoint(3, [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]),

Comment: I don't understand your question. You should consider reformulate it.

Comment: Both cases are valid.